# generate sequence in sql select

Tags: sql-server

I need to write a query that will generate a sort of sequenced ID for each record... so for example:

```
ID      Customer Name
-------------------------
C1000   customer #1
C1010   customer #2
C1020   customer #3
C1030   customer #4
```

now, these "C1000" ids don't exist... only the customer names.  I need to generate them when I do the select... so I can save off the output, and then import into the new system.

how can I do a:

```
select 
   'C' + (some kinda code/math that generates the count based on a sequence?  or row number?),
   name
from Customers
```

================================================

I ended up doing the following (so I could configure start# and increment size):

```
DECLARE @start int; 
DECLARE @inc int; 
set @start = 1000; 
set @inc = 10; 

Select 'C' + CAST(@start + (@inc * (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name))) as varchar) as NewID, Name
from customer
```

Comment: You'll need something to order by or the generated sequences will be unpredictable (will change between runs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) as in [this example](http://mysqlserverblog.com/2007/12/03/tsql-row_number_function.aspx).